# AJAX - Modal Popup Not In Generated Source - How'd They Do That?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

On the [Bloomberg.com](http://www.bloomberg.com) site, in the top right of the homepage there is a 'Sign In' link (next to their search textbox).  Upon clicking the link a simple-looking modal popup appears into which one can enter one's sign-in credentials.  Clean, elegant.  With the popup still visible I did a generated source check and there's no evidence of the modal popup html anywhere in it.  I'm wondering why the modal popup source is missing and, assuming it's coming from somewhere else, where it's coming from.  Can someone please explain it?

More generally I assume that Bloomberg's login dialog is ultimately transmitting its user data on an encrypted basis.  The home page itself is rendering as a standard http.  Is there some hidden - and secure, presumably https - means by which this site, and others I'm sure, is accomplishing its modal information gathering and posting, securely and distinct from the base homepage?  Any clarifications on how this is happening and the best practices for coding it would be appreciated.  Thanks!

-- Rick

Comment: The DIV for the modal pop-up is created using Javascript. And the login information is sent using HTTPS in the AJAX call.

Comment: If you need HTML for the popup you may use firebug or Chrome Developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

The popup is actually just presenting an iframe of this URL:

https://login.bloomberg.com/api/login?skin=&rt=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloomberg.com%2F&cc=0.13446950796060264

(And the iframe itself is presented over HTTPS, which covers the security issue you mentioned)

Comment: Related question.. When a user submits information into a form displayed through an iframe, how is a given outcome (say, a successful authentication) communicated back to the host page so that the modal popup can be closed?